# How to see (visualize) the robot orientation (Yaw) in rviz

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I need a help regarding a robot orientation. I made a node that calculate the orientation of the robot to some object in the map/ So I can get the Yaw from my transformation, but that is just a number. Is there any tool that can visualize that orientation??This the part of the code where I get the YAW

.... some code..
while (node.ok())
{

```
            //Speed and Yaw calculation
            tf::StampedTransform transform2;
        if(speed_count==9)
        {
                try{
                    listener.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_link",  
                                ros::Time(0), transform2);
            
                }
                    catch (tf::TransformException ex){};

                vel = hypotenuse(xlast,ylast, transform2.getOrigin().x(),transform2.getOrigin().y());
            if(vel<0.003){
                yaw = tf::getYaw(transform2.getRotation());
            }

            speed_count = 0;
            xlast = transform2.getOrigin().x(); ylast = transform2.getOrigin().y();
        }
        else speed_count++;
```

..... more code

Any help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49045/how-to-see-(visualize)-the-robot-orientation-(yaw)-in-rviz/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can simply [display the tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/TF) for `/base_link`. That way you not only get the orientation, but the full pose as a coordinate frame.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-11-24**:
I can do that through rviz??

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-24**:
If the /base_link tf is being published (it seems like it is from your code) you can visualize it directly in rviz. Just make sure you choose a proper fixed frame in the global options, such as /map

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-11-24**:
But that gives me a quaternion X Y Z W. So what that mean for the robot orientation??  I have for example a Yaw of 80 deg. So what the relation of that to the quaternion X Y Z W?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-11-24**:
The TF display in rviz will show you a coordinate frame (a red/green/blue thing as the ones in the link provided). If you are interested in the numerical value of the angle in degrees it won't help you, but then again if you only want that you don't need rviz. All it takes is a std::cout statement.